# Web app Libraries are not found Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Web app Libraries are not found in Eclipse.

I tried the following steps:

**Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Web app Libraries not found**

**Right Click Project -> Build Path -> Add Libraries -> Web app Libraries are not found**

Any other way to find the Web app Libraries in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

**Import these libraries from another project**. If no any project exist then create new one and only import libraries from this new project.